# Series doubt from problem solving strategies

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image: Problem Solving Strategies screenshot]

> My questions:
>
> 1) How come they take $ x_n=\lambda^n$ for some suitable lambda and then they claim that $x_{n-1}=\lambda^{n-1}$ and like that. What's the assurance that such a lambda exits? Firstly, $x_n$ is more of a function and so it may necessarily not be representable as a power form right? Their writing means $x_i=\lambda^i$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$. But how's that possible?
>
> 2) The general solution comes as roots of lambda. And with some particular constants $a,b$. But how did they use the roots? And how is $a,b$ fixed?

Comment: Bump, can anyone reply back? I don't think that the characteristic equation is correct. I think that $q\lambda^2+p\lambda-1=0$ would be the correct characteristic equation. Please confirm this as well

Answer (score 1):

For 1, the assumption that $x_n=\lambda^n$ implies that $x_{n-1}=\lambda^{n-1}$.  We are just substituting $n-1$ for $n$ in the assumption.  $x_n$ is not a function, it is a way of referring to the $n$th term of the sequence generated by the recurrence.  Once we are given $(1)$ plus $x_0,x_1$ we have all the information we need to calculate any $x_n$ we want.  It is easy to build a spreadsheet to do so.  If we want $x_{100000}$ it would be nice to have a way to compute it without adding up $100000$ lines.  The assumption is proved to work (unless the roots of the characteristic equation are the same) by what follows.  In the discussions I have seen of this there is no justification of the assumption.  It is as if the solution were magically obtained and now we justify it.  You should be able to verify that $\lambda^n$ satisfies the original recurrence when $\lambda$ is one of the two roots of the characteristic equation.  We then note that the system is linear, that any multiple of a solution is still a solution and the sum of any two solutions is still a solution.  The solution $a\lambda_1^n+b\lambda_2^n$ will satisfy the recurrence $(1)$ for any $a,b$.  Given two values, most often $x_0,x_1$, we can find $a,b$ by solving a pair of simultaneous equations.

Comment: Sir, can you explain me using generating functions?

Comment: And can anyone show me using generating functions how the characteristic equation is like that?